# Get all selected values from bootstrap multiselect using PHP?

Tags: php, multi-select

Having an off-day today and can't seem to figure this one out for some reason (feeling like a blonde moment).

I am trying to use the bootstrap (3.3.7) multiselect field 
**EX:**

```html
<select multiple class="form-control" id="select_example">
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
    <option value="four">4</option>
    <option value="five">5</option>
</select>
```

When I submit (submits via ajax), the MySQL db receives all the data, but for multiselect fields, it is only the value of the last selected option in the options list.

How would I go about getting all of the selected option values and putting them into an array or comma separated string?
Selected: 2,4,5
Current value to db: five
Expected: two,four,five (or something of the like)

Is there a PHP solution for this, or jquery (or combo of the two?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
if($_POST['aircraft']){
    $_POST['aircraft'] = implode(', ', $_POST['aircraft']);
}
```

with a select multiselect with the name aircraft the above code converts the returned array of the multiselect, and converts it into a comma separated string.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select multiple class="form-control" id="select_example" name="options[]">
<option value="one">1</option>
<option value="two">2</option>
<option value="three">3</option>
<option value="four">4</option>
<option value="five">5</option>
```

```
$options = implode(',', $_POST['options']);
```